# Azure Cognitive Search: hybrid search with synonym map not possible?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have setup a Azure Cognitive Search index that I query with Vector search and keyword search, so we ended up in Hybrid Search. We need to add a synonym map now to improve our search results (the client has very specific language/words it uses. We need extend the general vector search with specific synonyms like USA => United States of America...

The code:

```
responses = search_client.search(
                search_text=question, #both keyword
                vectors= [vector], #and vector search
                select=["title", "answer", "question", "url"],
                top=2,
                query_caption_highlight=False
            )
```

If I disable the vectors, synonyms are used. But I still need the hybrid too.
**Is there any possibility to have both Hybrid search while having the keyword search using synonym maps?**